# Need help shell script to filter owner machine list

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have automatically changing password for every machines almost 2000 hosts. I have wrote below script.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  while read line
  do
  ip=`cat /root/file | awk ' { print $1 } '`
  owner=`cat /root/file | awk ' { print $2 } '`
  function randpass() {
  [ "$2" == "13" ] && CHAR="[:alnum:]" || CHAR="[:graph:]"
  cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "$CHAR" | head -c 8
  echo
  }
  newpass=`randpass`
  ssh $ip "mkdir -p /home/dev/.vnc"
  ssh $ip "echo $newpass | vncpasswd -f > /home/dev/.vnc/passwd"
  ssh $ip "chown -R dev:dev /home/dev/.vnc"
  ssh $ip "chmod 0600 /home/dev/.vnc/passwd"
  ssh $ip "echo "$newpass" | passwd --stdin dev"
   #ssh $ip "echo -e "dev:$newpass" | chpasswd"
   echo -e "$ip:$newpass:$owner" >> `date +"%d-%m-%y"`
   done < /root/file
```

It genarates below output to file:

```
  10.10.10.100:password1:bob1
  10.10.10.101:password2:bob2
  10.10.10.102:password3:bob3
  10.10.10.104:password5:bob1
  10.10.10.102:password4:bob3
  10.10.10.108:password8:bob1
```

I need to add additional script Please help

From above file output I need to generate  files like below:

file name bob1 (this is username):

```
  10.10.10.108:password8
  10.10.10.104:password5
  10.10.10.100:password1
```

file name bob2:

```
  10.10.10.101:password2
```

File name bob3:

```
    10.10.10.102:password3
    10.10.10.102:password4
```

Note: users names may change and add more users name

Comment: You can use `grep` on the generated file. For example you have this `echo -e "$ip:$newpass:$owner" >> `outputFile``....then you can do something like `outputFile | grep bob1 > bob1.log` or something like that.

Comment: You might want to get a bit more shell programming experience before writing a script to change the password on 2000 hosts, it seems there's a lot could go wrong if you don't get the script absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AWK:

```
awk -F: -vOFS=: '{ a = $NF; NF--; print > a }' file
```

The command sets input and output [field separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html#Field-Separators) to `:`. The script saves the last field `$NF` into `a` variable, decrements the number of fields, and prints the rest of the fields to a file with filename equal to the value of `a` by means of the [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) (`>`).

Note, it is reliable to work with a colon as a field separator, because we get only the last field, and the last field is a username where the colon character is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, Its working  I am planning to send a mail to its users is it possible bob1 is the mail id and redirecting bob1file  are the machines and password. I need to echo username and user machines with password

Comment: @sagar, if the passwords do not contain colons, then you can access the field as `$NF` (after decrement operation). Actually, you can access the colon-separated fields by their numbers: `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. I've counted the fields from the end, because it is safer (I don't know if the password field may contain colons, in particular). So you can print the desired fields and redirect the result to a file, e.g. `{ a = $NF; NF--;  print a "@" $1 " - " $NF > a }`

Comment: I will change to space in field separator,  because password created is random it may create colon consist one. or tab is the best option?

Comment: @sagar, well, tab is a good choice. Space is not as good, since the password is more likely to contain a space rather than a tab. However, it depends on the algorithm generating the password